# Moving 50 Sprites in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone

I have about 50 small sprites I want to move around a layer.  I've been
looking at a couple of different options.  What would be the most
efficient way of doing this?  (They will be constantly moving).

I've looked at PathAction ( http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=63
)
I've also thought about just a straight up [sprite schedule: @selector
(step:) interval:0.1];

What do you think would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it - my sprites enter the screen from the right and travel to the left to disappear.  I have 3 different textures the sprites use that is randomly assigned as the sprites are generated, so there are only 3 images applied no matter how many sprites I make.

```
id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
```